# Can I check the HTTP Status code in watin?

Tags: .net, watin

Is there a way to check the status code of a request in watin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it seems that it's not possible out of the box so I came up with a solution that might work. I'm not 100 % sure, but I blogged about it here: http://blog.tomasjansson.com/2011/09/how-to-check-http-status-code-with-watin/

Comment: That solution looks very much like a rip-off of an earlier posted solution. Please give credit where credit is due... http://www.kongsli.net/nblog/2008/07/08/internet-explorer-automationwatin-catching-navigation-error-codes/

Comment: It's true, this feature is not supported by WatiN out of the box. I have added a feature request: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3435052&group_id=167632&atid=843730

Comment: @JesseWebb, I am referencing that blog post in my post. It is a colleague of mine that has written it. But maybe the link wasn't that clear :).

Comment: Sorry, must have glanced over it. I found both blog posts and this SO question in a Google search and I got mildly upset because status codes were such a pain to retrieve. I do like the Extension methods you wrote, very helpful abstraction of the solution!

Comment: Great. But be aware that it is not 100% accurate as I mention in the post.